# What's the better way to check if a String is empty than using String.trim().length() in Java 5/6?

Tags: java, string

There probably is a method to return the index of the first non-blank char in a String in Java5/6. But I cannot find it any more. A code anylizing tool says it is better than checking `String.trim().length()`.

Comment: What about iterating on the characters until end of string or character not blank?

Comment: I always do exactly trim().length(), and do not lose my sleep over such minor inefficiency.

Comment: Does you magic tool tell, *why* it is better? Maybe it's better to ignore that suggestion ;)

Comment: because trim() creates a new instance of String(), I guess.

Comment: @road to yamburg: You are absolutely correct. There is no reason to start worring about performance problems of this scale... you would be wasting your time at best, and at worst case you could end up not checking what you need. Just comment that you are making sure the String is not all spaces, and then trim() and check the length

Comment: Okay guys, I have found it finally from PMD rules of [InefficientEmptyStringCheck](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/strings.html): Since: PMD 3.6

`String.trim().length()` is an inefficient way to check if a String is really empty, as it creates a new String object just to check its size. Consider creating a static function that loops through a string, checking `Character.isWhitespace()` on each character and returning false if a non-whitespace character is found.

Comment: @road to yamburg Right, but it's actually a very small inefficiency, since the new `String` is created using the `substring` method, and therefore it shares the character storage (the `value` field) with the original `String`.

Comment: It shares the character storage, but String instance itself is allocated in heap. For large number of checks it make fragment heap quite a lot.

Comment: @road: `trim()` returns a new `String` **only** if its content is different from the `String` it's been called on, otherwise it returns itself (that's even documented so you can **rely** on it!). So the new `String` instance is **only** created in the (usually rare) case where there's a space at the start or end of the `String`.

Comment: Usually rare? This very much depends on data. For some inputs trailing spaces are common.

Comment: Apart from that: short-lived objects don't cause much problems to the JVM. And you can't get much more short-lived than the "middle string" in `foo.trim().isEmpty()`.

Comment: @road to yamburg - the fragmentation issue will depend on what GC the JVM is configured to use.

Comment: String concatenation caused me 10x times delay in request processing; had nothing but short-lived Strings. StringBuilder is invented for a cause. Same here.

Comment: @Stephen C: fragmentation may be noticeable or not, but it will happen. If it can be avoided, why not? (besides, I, if you read my first comment, do exactly trim().length() -- because in my apps this inefficiency doesn't matter).

Comment: @road: that's an **entirely** different problem. If String-concatentation slows down your code then it's the repeated (unnecessary) copying of char-arrays that's slowing you down. That's **not** "heap fragmentation".

Comment: I used words "heap fragmentation" only to sound smarter. Happens to me. What I meant to say is that unnecessary allocation gives extra, unnecessary, work to GC, which can be easily avoided.

Comment: @road: if by "easily" you mean "by introducing a new method that replaces a well-known idiom that everyone who reads the code will have to check before they know what the code actually does", then yes. ;-) Sorry, it's not meant as sarcastically as it probably sounds. I just want to remind everyone that developer time is *usually* (again this dangerous word!) more expensive than minuscule amounts of CPU time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd use the [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) [`CharMatcher`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html) class:

```
boolean onlyWhitespace = CharMatcher.WHITESPACE.matchesAllOf(input);
```

Comment: Perhaps s.matches("\\s*"); would do the same then? I personally prefer to stick to JRE libs whenever possible...

Comment: @road: in practice: yes, it will be the same. Strictly speaking it only tests a limited subset of whitespace characters, while `CharMatcher.WHITESPACE` contains all Unicode whitespace characters. Also, `.matches()` would require compiling the regex each time which might be slower.

Comment: Not sure "\\s" matches a limited subset. And regexp -- I can compile it once and use in an utility method StringUtils.isBlank(s).

Comment: @road: according to [`Pattern`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) it matches `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`. This means that many other Whitespace characters such as [U+200A](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200a/index.htm), [U+202F](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202f/index.htm), [U+3000](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3000/index.htm), ... are not detected). I don't know how much difference that'll make in practice, however.

Comment: Yes, just read docs there and there. Need to file a bug for Su... Oracle, I mean! :)

Answer (score 13):

I always like to use the Apache Commons StringUtils library. It has isEmpty() and is isBlank() which handles whitespace.

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

Not to mention the numerous other helpful methods in that class and the library in general.

Comment: (learned from @Joachim Sauer) Doesn't support all Unicode as CharMatcher does! ;)

Comment: If you're refering to his comments below 2 of the 3 unicode characters he lists work with StringUtils. Unless I'm doing something wrong,  StringUtils.isBlank((Character.toString('\u200A')); returns true and isEmpty returns false which should be correct. Same for \u3000. \u202F isn't considered blank by Java Character.isWhiteSpace so I'm not sure I'd want StringUtils to return true for that.

Comment: StringUtils.isEmpty() doesn't trim the string since v2. From javadoc: "NOTE: This method changed in Lang version 2.0. It no longer trims the String. That functionality is available in isBlank()." http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 7):

Java 11 introduces the "isBlank" method. See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isBlank()

> Returns true if the string is empty or contains only white space codepoints, otherwise false.

Answer (score 5):

Okay guys, I have found it finally from PMD rules of [InefficientEmptyStringCheck](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/strings.html):

> InefficientEmptyStringCheck:
>   Since:
>   PMD 3.6
>   String.trim().length() is an
>   inefficient way to check if a String
>   is really empty, as it creates a new
>   String object just to check its size.
>   Consider creating a static function
>   that loops through a string, checking
>   Character.isWhitespace() on each
>   character and returning false if a
>   non-whitespace character is found.

This is only a suggestion from PMD. To adopt it or not is depending on which has priority: the efficiency of programs or the time of programmers.

Answer (score 2):

Java 6 has introduced `String.isEmpty()`, so you could use it in conjunction with `String.trim()`.  You can also use regular expressions, for example using such a condition: `!str.matches("\\s*")`.

Comment: the issue is trim(). it creates (or may create an new instance of String) which is not efficient.

Comment: @VladimirDyuzhev That's what I would expect, but PMD stopped flagging it when I switched to .isEmpty() instead of .length()==1, even though I kept .trim() in

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test, whether it only contains whitespace characters, you can use RegEx

```
string.matches("\\s*")
```

Thinks it's more efficient than trim().isEmpty(), especially if you expect whitespaces and have long Strings, though I'm not sure how much effort it takes to compile the RegEx.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test for a string that has a zero length than using `isEmpty()` or `length() == 0` is the best way.

If you want to test if the string only contains whitespaces, then searching for the first non-whitespace character is more efficient because not intermediate object is created (as with `trim()`)

But in any case I too recommend Apache's commons `StringUtils.isEmpty()`as it nicely encapsulates all this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in String for this exact purpose.

```
String emptyString = "";
emptyString.isEmpty();
```

This will return true.

Comment: But this is not the same as `String.trim().length() == 0`! Just change your first line to `String emptyString = "\n"`. Your code will return false, whereas String.trim().length() == 0 will return true.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
  str!=null && str.trim().isEmpty()
```

Answer (score -4):

(Best way) `string.equals("")`

But also,

```
string.isEmpty()

string.equals(null)
```

Comment: `string.length() == 0` is **far** more efficient than `string.equals("")`

Comment: Not really a solution for strings with whitespaces only.

Comment: `string.equals(null)` always returns false or throws NullPointerException.